# Spatie Multi Tenant - Login Propietario - SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected

Tags: laravel-8, spatie

buenas noches.

Estoy configurando un proyecto con spatie/multitenancy y al configurar el modelo User para autenticar e iniciar sesión, agrego el trait UsesTenantConnection al modelo User, la autenticación es exitosa para los inquilinos, pero para el propietario no reconoce la conexión. Si uso el trait UsesLandlordConnection o ninguno de los dos trait en el modelo User, al iniciar sesión, sea en el propietario o en los inquilinos, reconoce la conexión del propietario, y en el propietario se accede sin problemas, para el propietario esta bien, pero para los inquilinos le muestra mensaje de credenciales incorrectas, debido a que esta considerando la conexión del propietario.

Aqui el error que me sale cuando uso el trait UsesTenantConnection e inicio sesión en el propietario.

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = micorreo@correo.com limit 1)

http://multitenancy_spatie.test:82/login
```

Y aqui los archivos relevantes de configuración

En el kernel

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'tenant' => [
        \Spatie\Multitenancy\Http\Middleware\NeedsTenant::class,
        \Spatie\Multitenancy\Http\Middleware\EnsureValidTenantSession::class,
    ]
];
```

config('database')

```
[
 "default" => "landlord",
 "connections" => [
   "tenant" => [
     "driver" => "mysql",
     "url" => null,
     "host" => "127.0.0.1",
     "port" => "3306",
     "database" => null,//Tenant Autr
     "username" => "root",
     "password" => "",
     "unix_socket" => "",
     "charset" => "utf8mb4",
     "collation" => "utf8mb4_unicode_ci",
     "prefix" => "",
     "prefix_indexes" => true,
     "strict" => true,
     "engine" => null,
     "options" => [],
   ],
   "landlord" => [
     "driver" => "mysql",
     "url" => null,
     "host" => "127.0.0.1",
     "port" => "3306",
     "database" => "multitenancy_spatie",
     "username" => "root",
     "password" => "",
     "unix_socket" => "",
     "charset" => "utf8mb4",
     "collation" => "utf8mb4_unicode_ci",
     "prefix" => "",
     "prefix_indexes" => true,
     "strict" => true,
     "engine" => null,
     "options" => [],
   ],
 ],
]
```

config('multitenancy')

```
[
 "tenant_finder" => "Spatie\Multitenancy\TenantFinder\DomainTenantFinder",
 "tenant_artisan_search_fields" => [
   "id",
 ],
 "switch_tenant_tasks" => [
   "Spatie\Multitenancy\Tasks\SwitchTenantDatabaseTask",
 ],
 "tenant_model" => "Spatie\Multitenancy\Models\Tenant",
 "queues_are_tenant_aware_by_default" => true,
 "landlord_database_connection_name" => "landlord",
 "current_tenant_container_key" => "currentTenant",
 "actions" => [
   "make_tenant_current_action" => "Spatie\Multitenancy\Actions\MakeTenantCurrentAction",
   "forget_current_tenant_action" => "Spatie\Multitenancy\Actions\ForgetCurrentTenantAction",
   "make_queue_tenant_aware_action" => "Spatie\Multitenancy\Actions\MakeQueueTenantAwareAction",
   "migrate_tenant" => "Spatie\Multitenancy\Actions\MigrateTenantAction",
 ],
 "queueable_to_job" => [
   "Illuminate\Mail\SendQueuedMailable" => "mailable",
   "Illuminate\Notifications\SendQueuedNotifications" => "notification",
   "Illuminate\Events\CallQueuedListener" => "class",
   "Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent" => "event",
 ],
]
```

Archivo .env

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:millave
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://multitenancy_spatie.test:82

DB_CONNECTION=landlord
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=multitenancy_spatie
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Archivo de rutas -> routes/web.php

```
Route::domain('{tenant}.multitenancy_spatie.test')->middleware('tenant')->group(function() {
    // routes
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('auth.login');
    });
    Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
        return view('dashboard_tenant');
    })->name('dashboard');
});

Route::domain('multitenancy_spatie.test')->group(function() {
    // routes
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    })->name('home');
    
    Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
        return view('dashboard');
    })->name('dashboard');
});
```

He revisado en github: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-multitenancy/issues/224, en ese issue tratan sobre el mismo error, pero no he logrado dar con la solución para iniciar sesion.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: El código y mensajes de error deben ir en formato texto y no en imagen. Por favor edita tu pregunta haciendo clic en [edit] y corrige lo que haga falta. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se si sea la forma correcta, pero lo solucione cambiando la configuración por defecto de la conexión, dependiendo si se accede desde el propietario o el inquilino, agregue la configuración al método boot, del AppServiceProvider.

En el modelo User ya no consideré ninguno de los trait UsesTenantConnection, UsesLandlordConnection. Tal cual, en una instalación limpia.

Así quedó la configuración adicional, con esto ya pude autenticar mis usuarios tanto del propietario como inquilinos.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
    }

    public function boot()
    {
        if ('multitenancy_spatie.test' === request()->getHost()) {
            config(['database.default' => 'landlord']);
        } else{
            config(['database.default' => 'tenant']);
        }
    }
}
```